# Is there a way to have one ArFragment and one normal fragment in a ViewPager Adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, arcore

I am trying to developp an app and I have a camera activity. My intention is to have two separate fragments that hold two different functionalities that use the camera (sort of like capture image/video in regular cameras). I have the ViewPager set up with a TabLayout. As a placeholder, I put the camera data as backgroud.

However, one of the fragments needs AR, so I am trying to incorporate ARCore. However, making the first fragment an ArFragment messes up the second one. I haven't seen much documentation around on the subject. Is there a way to make this work? Should I take a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the ArFragment with in viewpager using `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

As you said, there are some issues using it that way.

- ArFragment requires Fullscreen, it hides the activity toolbar, status bar...
- When you come-back/swipe to the other fragment, the view is messed up most of the time.
- There will be a visible drop in frames because Arcore is busy understanding the environment.

Possible solutions:

- Extend ArFragment, You can control the `onResume` & `onPause`, helps in performance. Because by default the next fragment in the adapter will always reach `onResume`
- Use ArSceneView directly (more code, but more control over the session, lifecycles)